# How to read image ALT tag using Simple HTML Dom Parser?

Tags: html-parsing

I would like to fetch the information contained in the ALT attribute of the image on the website using Simple HTML Dom Parser. Here's the code:

I need to fetch only "pasazbiurowy.pl" as a plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="//image.ceneostatic.pl/data/shops/19572/logo.jpg" alt="pasazbiurowy.pl" data-original="//image.ceneostatic.pl/data/shops/19572/logo.jpg" class=" lazyloaded">
```